# How can I make object data editable by object method only in js

Tags: javascript, object

I have object **a** which contains data as well as methods .

```
var a = {
  name:'alisha',
  country:'japan',
  edit:function(){
   // this method should only be edit values of name and country property except this method
 }
}
```

I don't have any idea whether I can do something like this or not.Yes I can edit it directly like:-

a.name = 'alisha2';

But I should't be able to access in this way. I want to call edit method and edit method should edit my data for me.

a.edit({'name':'alisha update'});

I don't know we can do this or not. Is it possible ?

**Please don't use any libs or frameworks with pure js only**

Answer (score 1):

The most direct and simple answer to your question is no.  You cannot mark a property on an object as private... however, where's the fun in that answer.  Let's take a look at a few different approaches for achieving something *like* that.

**Note**: For the sake of simplicity and time, I'll most likely only implement portions of the code example provided.

**Note**: While your example shows an `edit()` method that takes a object, chances are you'll want to use more explicit accessors/modifiers instead (for the same reasons you want private properties) and this is what I demonstrate below.  If you feel the `edit()` method is more appropriate for your use case, you can easily replace the modifiers I define.

#### (Probably) The Best Answer

The best answer was outlined by Joseph Fehrman before I was able to finish writing my answer.  This solution can be accomplished 2 different ways.  I prefer the way I show below as it treats the IIFE proposed by Joseph as a class/constructor that can be reused.

```js
    function A(name, country) {
        var _name = name;       // I use backslashes as convention to show the variables are meant to be private.
        var _country = country;

        this.getName = function getName() {
            return _name;
        };

        this.setName = function setName(newName) {
            _name = newName;
        }
    }

    var a = new A("Calvin", "USA");
    console.log("Name: " + a.getName());
```

This takes advantage of JS's closures.  The variables `_name` and `_country` can only be accessed within the scoped defined by `A`.  Additional functions in that scope can access these variables, but nothing else can.

The advantage of this approach is truly private data that can only be accessed by methods defined in `A`'s scope.  It also doesn't require any external anything and only takes advantage JS features that are supported by every browser (hopefully).  The disadvantage with this approach is you really don't have readonly properties as you specified in your example.

#### A Different Answer

You mention you don't want to use any external libraries or frameworks.  However, if you were willing to use a compiler, which doesn't require additional files to be sent to your client, you could use TypeScript to achieve this behavior (kinda).  Again, you would define a class from which you could generate `a` and you might define it like:

```
class A {
    constructor(private _name: string, private _country: string) { }

    /* Option 1 - Similar to the pure JS solution below. */
    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(name: string) {
        if(!/^\w+$/.test(name)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid name.');
        }

        this._name = name;
    }

    /* Option 2  - Closer to what you specified */
    get country(): string {
        return this._country;
    }

    setCountry(country: string) {
        this._country = country;
    }
}

let a = new A('Calvin', 'USA');

// a.name = "New Name"; // Throws an error: "Invalid name."

console.log(a.name);
```

(You can run the above example and play around with it on this [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20_name%3A%20string%2C%20private%20_country%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F*%20Option%201%20-%20Similar%20to%20the%20pure%20JS%20solution%20below.%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20get%20name()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this._name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20set%20name(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(!%2F%5E%5Cw%2B%24%2F.test(name))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error('Invalid%20name.')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this._name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F*%20Option%202%20%20-%20Closer%20to%20what%20you%20specified%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20get%20country()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this._country%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20setCountry(country%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this._country%20%3D%20country%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A('Calvin'%2C%20'USA')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20a.name%20%3D%20%22New%20Name%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20Throws%20an%20error%3A%20%22Invalid%20name.%22%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(a.name)%3B))

With this approach, you now have a readonly property (`country`) that can be accessed exactly like you demonstrated in your example code and modified explicitly with a modifier.  You also have a property `name` that looks and acts like a normal property, but you can have control over what value is read and how the property is modified through a function.

However, this approach warrants a few warnings:

**Warning 1**: Obviously, the approach taken with `name` can have unexpected side effects.  If outside code attempts to modify `name` in a way forbidden by the setter and an error isn't thrown, the bug may never be caught and errors can occur later during execution.  That being said, I still like that approach where appropriate.

**Warning 2**: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and is compiled (really transpiled) to JavaScript at some point.  If you try to access any private properties outside of TypeScript, you will notice there is nothing stopping you.

#### TypeScript, but Longer

We could get a little trickier in how we implement this in JS, if we're willing to use ECMAScript 2015 (which is supported by most modern browsers).  We could make it so that prying eyes wouldn't be able to view a hidden property and define simple accessors/modifiers the hidden properties.  We can do this with [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)).  This approach might look something like:

```js
    function A(name, country) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, '_name', {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable:   false,
            writable:     true
        });

        this._name = name;

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
            configurable: false,
            enumerable:   true,
            get:          function getName() {
                return this._name;
            }
            /**
             * If you liked the setter defined in TypeScript, you could accomplish the
             * same thing using:
             *
             * set:     function setName(name) {
             *    this._name = name;
             * }
             */
        });
    }

    A.prototype.setName = function setName(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    var a = new A('Calvin', 'USA');
    console.log(a.name);
    a.name = 'Bertrand';    // Silently fails
    console.log(a.name);    // => "Calvin"
```

This is what the TypeScript example above *might* transpile to (it doesn't actually transpile *exactly* to this).  There are a few things to note.  First, `name` is publicly accessible, but not publicly modifiable.  However, `_name`, the value from which `name` is derived, is both publicly accessible and modifiable.  This is partially demonstrated by me defining `setName()` on the prototype chain instead of `this` in the constructor.  This approach simply makes `_name` difficult to find; however, this too has some negative consequences.

Since `_name` is not private, anybody can purposely modify it if they know it exists.  Even if they don't know it exists, they can overwrite it by adding a property to the object they didn't know existed.  This may happen innocently, for example, if the programmer is trying to track changes to properties without cloning the original version.  As with almost all unexpected behavior, this can have unintended and unnoticed side-effects that could cause bugs later on down the road.

Comment: Hey gave you a vote as your answer I felt had the most options and explained it better than I did.  Could you do me a favor and make the code sections executable?

Comment: @JosephFehrman Thank you.  I made the JS code sections executable and added a link to a page where you can execute the TS code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a design pattern for this.  It is called the revealing module pattern.  It works like this.

```js
var a = function(){
  var name = 'alisha';
  var country = 'japan';
  
  function setName(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  
  function setCountry(newCountry) {
    country = newCountry;
  }
  
  function getCountry() {
    return country;
  }
  
  function getName() {
    return name;
  }
  
  function edit() {
    // Do stuff.
  }

  return {
    'getName' : getName,
    'getCountry' : getCountry,
    'setName' : setName,
    'setCountry' : setCountry,
    'edit' : edit
  }
};

var newA = new a();
document.querySelector('#out').append(document.createTextNode(newA.getName()));
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: For those looking for more information or examples of this pattern here is a link to a site that explains it in more detail.  https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't with this type of object. In javascript the property of an object is always public.

However if it was an instantiated object you can create a sort of private variable.

```
function Person(name,country){
   var _name = name;
   var _country = country;

   this.edit = function(obj){
       _name = obj.name;
       _country = obj.country;
   };

   this.getName = function(){
       return _name;
   };

   this.getCountry = function(){
       return _country;
   };
}
```

Note that _name is not accessible through the outside:

```
var girl = new Person("alisha","japan");
girl.getName(); // alisha
```

Comment: It's not true that you can't do this. You can create read-only properties using getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

use a [**`setter`**](https://javascriptplayground.com/es5-getters-setters/) method for the specific property which you want to edit privately

```
var a = {
  name:'alisha',
  country:'japan',
  set Name(name){
     this.name = name
  }
}

a.Name = 'pokemon' // use the Name setter method to edit name property
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Now you can call a.edit({'name':'alisha update'}); to edit name. Even you can change name and country both by calling a.edit({'name':'alisha update','country':'India'});

```
var a = {
    name:'alisha',
    country:'japan',
    edit:function(values){
      for (var i=0;i<Object.keys(values).length;i++) {
        a[Object.keys(values)[i]]=Object.values(values)[i];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I loved the way you did it but peoples can change edit method with next function so how can i make it private